# C array parameter and return type for Objective-C methods

Tags: objective-c, arrays, clang, return-type

In my latest version of XCode (4.6.2), it turns out that you can use C array types as the parameter types and return type of an Objective-C method:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@end
@implementation Foo
+ (float[2])bar:(int[4])x { // takes an array of 4 ints, and returns an array of 2 floats
  return (float[2]){ x[0] + x[1], x[0] - x[1] };
}
@end
```

This is surprising since C specifically does not allow arrays types as the parameter types and return type of a C function (it automatically treats them as the pointer type instead). This means that Objective-C methods are not syntactic sugar for C functions?

Is this documented anywhere? I can't seem to find any.

Using the above code, it seems to work correctly:

```
int qux[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
float *baz = [Foo bar:qux];
NSLog(@"%f %f", baz[0], baz[1]); // prints 3.000000 -1.000000
```

Further investigating the type information for this method; apparently there is a new type encoding syntax for array types:

```
Method method = class_getClassMethod([Foo class], @selector(bar:));
NSLog(@"%s", method_getTypeEncoding(method)); // prints [2f]24@0:8[4i]16
NSLog(@"%s", @encode(float[2])); // prints [2f]
```

However, it seems that my Cocoa (I'm using Mac OS X 10.7) does not yet recognize this type encoding. The following throws `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: +[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:]: unsupported return type encoding spec '[2f]'

```
[Foo methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(bar:)];
```

Is this a new Mac OS X 10.8 thing or something?

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty odd.   Maybe a C++ '11-ism?

In general, the encoding strings used by the runtime are considered an implementation detail and aren't really intended to be used for such purposes.  They'll work well enough for relatively simple uses, but things quickly go off the rails for complex types.  Similarly, language arrays as pass-by-value arguments and/or return types are generally avoided beyond the implied array of, say, a CGRect/NSRect.

As you have discovered, type encodings change over time and sometimes there is a mismatch between the parsers in the system and the encodings generated by the compiler.  10.8 may or may not be able to parse that.